# Displaying Links for Images in PHP

Tags: php

My php will download a series of images into the local server (media/image1.jpg...).

Now how do I display this as a link? So that when user click on it, then it will show the image in another tab.

I could display the images using `echo '<img src="'.$link.'" /><br />';`

But how do I just show it as a link?

Comment: wrap it around the link.. <a href ="#"><img src ="" /></a>

Comment: if another tab/window use <a href ="target_file.jpg" target="_blank"><img src ="small_file.jpg" /></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use html a href, code shown below

```
    <?php
    echo "<a href='".$link."' target='_blank'>CLICK THIS LINK</a><br>";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use it like a link

```
echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><img src="'.$link.'" /></a>';
```